# W-boson mass eigenstates after electroweak symmetry breaking

Tags: particle-physics, higgs

A question about how the physical $W^{\pm}_{\mu}, Z_{\mu}, A_{\mu} $ masses arise:

We have the covariant derivative:

$$ D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} - \frac{ig}{2}\begin{pmatrix} W^3 & \sqrt{2} w^+ \\ \sqrt{2}W^- & -W^3 \end{pmatrix}  - \frac{ig'}{2} \mathcal{I}B_{\mu}$$

When the symmetry is broken by the Higgs VEV \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ u \end{pmatrix} :

$$ SU(2)_W \times U(1)_Y \rightarrow U(1) $$

And we expand around the vacuum, we obtain, after expanding the kinetic terms $(D_{\mu} \phi)^{\dagger}(D_{\mu} \phi) $

$$ \mathcal{L_{kinetic}} = \frac{g^2}{2}u^2W^+_{\mu}W^{-\mu} + (\frac{-g}{2} W^3_{\mu} + \frac{g'}{2}B_{\mu})(\frac{-g}{2}W^{3\mu} + \frac{g'}{2}B^{\mu}) + ... $$

When we identify $$W^{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (W^1_{\mu} \pm W^2_{\mu}) $$

We see that the first term gives a term $ \propto (W_1)^2 + (W_2)^2$, which has the form of a mass term.

**My question is why we call the charged $W^{\pm}$ bosons the mass eigenstates, but it looks from my naive calculation that the $W_1, W_2$ are also mass eigenstates.**

In addition, why does the mass term in the Lagrangian for the charged W bosons take the form:

$$ \frac{g^2u^2}{2} W^+_{\mu} W^{-\mu}$$ instead of the individual $W^+$ and $W^-$ mass terms? Some textbooks mention 'canonical normalization' but I can't find any detailed explaination.

I looked at this previous answer: [Electroweak interaction: From $W^{1}_{\mu},W^{2}_{\mu},W^{3}_{\mu},B_{\mu}$ to $W^{\pm},Z_{\mu},A_{\mu}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126037/electroweak-interaction-from-w1-mu-w2-mu-w3-mu-b-mu-to) but it seems like that author had the opposite problem to me.

Comment: There is a degeneracy so you could use the 1,2 basis or the +- basis. But since you know about charge as well as mass, you know which one is better.

Comment: @AHusain, is it correct to say that the $W_1, W_2 $ bosons are also mass eigenstates?

Comment: To answer why mass and charge eigenstates are used you need to understand the subject of superselection rules. This is discussed here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/why-certain-superpositions-of-quantum-states-are-supressed/11704#11704.